Wagmi extract error type from async mutation
I have the following code:
import { useDeployContract } from 'wagmi';

function Component() {
  const { deployContractAsync } = useDeployContract();

  function handleClick() {
    try {
      const txnHash = await deployContractAsync({...});
    } catch (e) {
      // typed `e`?
    }
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      click me
    </button>
  )
}

How can I use the error types wagmi provides?
In these docs, wagmi says if I do const { deployContractAsync, error } = useDeployContract(); then error is strongly typed, but I can't access error in the catch branch.

The best ergonomics I was able to get is this:
import { useDeployContract } from 'wagmi';
import { DeployContractErrorType } from '@wagmi/core';


function Component() {
  ...
    } catch (e) {
      const error = e as DeployContractErrorType;
      // now `error` is typed
    }
  ...
}

